# What is the make and the model of this seaplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, seaplane, ultralight

What is the model of this seaplane?
[image: Seaplane]

Answer (score 6):

This is a Progressive Aerodyne [SeaRey](http://www.searey.com/), a kit aircraft. Also on:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Aerodyne_SeaRey) and
- [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imQ0d4oP3J4).

About 500 of this make had been built up to 2011 according to the Wikipedia article.

[image]
<sup>(Source: [Light Sport Hangar Flyin'](http://light-sport-hangar-flyin.blogspot.fr/2011/02/hot-off-water.html))</sup>

This one is seemingly registered in the Philippines ("RP"), I read that at some point experimental aircraft had been grounded in the Philippines, but don't know if this was temporary only.